# Qt two classes access each other

Tags: c++, qt, class

Let's say I have a `Class A` which inherits from `QMainWindow`, and a `Class B`. The code is like this:

In `a.h`:

```
#ifndef A_H
#define A_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include "b.h"

class A : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    A(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~A();

    B TestingB;

    int tryingNumA = 0;
    void getNumB() {
        qDebug() << TestingB.tryingNumB; //worked
    }
};

#endif // A_H
```

In `b.h`:

```
#ifndef B_H
#define B_H

#include <QDebug>

class A;

class B
{
public:
    B();

    int tryingNumB = 1;

    A *testingA;
    void getNumA() {
        qDebug() << testingA->tryingNumA; //did not work, error: invalid use of incomplete type 'class A'
    }
};

#endif // B_H
```

And it is easy to get `Class B` elements in `Class A`, but I also want to get `Class A` elements in `Class B`(I want these two `Class` can access each other), the code I tried did not work. Is that the reason because `Class A` inherits from `QMainWindow`?
In order to achieve that, what can I do? 
Thanks.

Comment: Is B supposed to be a window/dialog? Also you didn't create a new object testingA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try moving `B::getNumA()` to the implementation file. Thus you would have something like

```
// b.cpp
#include "b.h"
#include "a.h"

 void b::getNumA() {
    qDebug() << testingA->tryingNumA; //did not work, error: invalid use of incomplete type 'class A'
}
```

The goal is to break the circular dependency between the headers.

Comment: I tried the way you provided, and it worked now, Thanks. But I have the following question, if I `#include 'a.h'` in `b.h` or just not include, it will get the incomplete type class error, and if I `#include 'a.h'` in `b.cpp`, the error will not show and it will work. Can you tell me why it must be included in .cpp file?